# UITableView not displaying data.

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm new to iOS and just trying to get data to display in `UITableView`. I basically have a project set up about authors. I want to display author names etc. So i have an Author model and `AuthorsViewController` which is a datasource and delegate for `UITableView` etc. I'm using storyboard (`MainStoryboard`) tableview and managed to connect it to `AuthorsViewController` in the "Identity Inspector".

Image of Storyboard if it helps, thanks:

Here, first, is the model: Author.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Author : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *book;
@property (nonatomic) int year;

@end
```

Author.m

```
#import "Author.h"

@implementation Author

@end
```

Here is the AuthorsViewController.h

```
@interface AuthorViewController : UITableViewController
<UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>

@end
```

And AuthorsViewController.m

```
#import "AuthorViewController.h"

@interface AuthorViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *authors;

@end

@implementation AuthorViewController

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _authors = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    Author *auth = [[Author alloc] init];

    [auth setName:@"David Powers"];
    [auth setBook:@"PHP Solutions"];
    [auth setYear:2010];
    [_authors addObject:auth];

    auth = [[Author alloc] init];
    [auth setName:@"Lisa Snyder"];
    [auth setBook:@"PHP security"];
    [auth setYear:2011];
    [_authors addObject:auth];

    auth = [[Author alloc] init];
    [auth setName:@"Rachel Andrew"];
    [auth setBook:@"CSS3 Tips, Tricks and Hacks"];
    [auth setYear:2012];
    [_authors addObject: auth];

}
```

[image]
    #pragma mark - Table view data source

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [_authors count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"AuthorCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (cell != nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]
                initWithStyle: UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    Author *currentAuthor = [_authors objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    [[cell textLabel] setText: [currentAuthor name]];

    NSLog(@"%@", [currentAuthor name]);

    return cell;
}

@end
```

Comment: Not sure what your specific problem is, but the line `if (cell != nil)` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` should be `if (cell == nil)`.

Comment: Is cellForRowAtIndexPath being called? Can you put breakpointed inside the method and see if it step into and if it is not, I suspect, there is something wrong with datasource setup.

Comment: I second that it should be if (cell == nil)

Comment: Could it also be that he is allocating memory 3 times for the same variable?? maybe have 3 seperate variable names?

Comment: Make sure the UITableView has its delegate and datasource set to the view controller.  Set a break point in one of the delegate methods to make sure this part is wired up correctly.

Comment: @TimothyMoose you are right. It should be "if (cell == nil)" and not "if (cell != nil)" changed that line and it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you made the table view with its cell in the storyboard, you don't need the if (cell == nil) clause at all. You also need to call [self.tableView reloadData] as the last line in viewDidLoad.

Comment: Yep ! It should be "if (cell == nil)" and not "if (cell != nil)" changed that line and it worked. Incidentaly it works even without "[self.tableView reloadData]" in "viewDidLoad", is this normal? Thank you anyways.

Comment: @TendaiK, it depends on how the data is loaded. I guess in your case, the data is set up before the table calls its data source methods. Did you delete the if (cell == nil) clause? You don't need it when you make the table view in the storyboard.